# Extracting a json field using Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have multiple fields stored as part of my log in elastic search. I am using Kibana to query the fields.One of the fields has a json object. I need to extract certain fields from  the json object. Is there  a way to do it using Kibana?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of present Kibana does not support nested json objects.
There was some work being done - https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1084

You can separate out fields you want from nested object to parent level key-value pair and then Kibana will be able to visualize it.

Comment: Thank you , is there a way to do this using elastic search query ?

Comment: kibana is just visualization tool which runs on top of Elasticsearch index. You will have to take out the fields that you want from json object and index them in ES. Kibana will pick them up

Comment: I had a similar question. You need to do some processing before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63413555/transform-string-into-json-so-that-its-searchable-in-kibana-elasticsearch