# Transform String into JSON so that it's searchable in Kibana/Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I have `Elasticsearch`, `Filebeat` and `Kibana` running on a Windows machine. `Filebeat` log has a proper log file and is listening to the path. When I look on the data in `Kibana` it looks fine.

My issue is that the `message` field is a String.

**Example of one log line:**

```
12:58:09.9608 Trace {"message":"No more Excel rows found","level":"Trace","logType":"User","timeStamp":"2020-08-14T12:58:09.9608349+02:00","fingerprint":"226fdd2-e56a-4af4-a7ff-724a1a0fea24","windowsIdentity":"mine","machineName":"NAME-PC","processName":"name","processVersion":"1.0.0.1","jobId":"957ef018-0a14-49d2-8c95-2754479bb8dd","robotName":"NAME-PC","machineId":6,"organizationUnitId":1,"fileName":"GetTransactionData"}
```

So what I would like to have now is that String converted to a JSON so that it is possible to search in `Kibana` for example for the `level` field.

I already had a look on `Filebeat`. There I tried to enable [LogStash](https://www.elastic.co/blog/a-practical-introduction-to-logstash) . But then the data does not come anymore to Elasticsearch. And also the log file is not genereated into the `LogStash` folder.

Then I downloaded `LogStash` via [install guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/running-logstash-windows.html), but unfortunately I got this message:

```
C:\Users\name\Desktop\logstash-7.8.1\bin>logstash.bat 
Sending
Logstash logs to C:/Users/mine/Desktop/logstash-7.8.1/logs which
is now configured via log4j2.properties ERROR: Pipelines YAML file is
empty. Location:
C:/Users/mine/Desktop/logstash-7.8.1/config/pipelines.yml usage:  
bin/logstash -f CONFIG_PATH [-t] [-r] [] [-w COUNT] [-l LOG]  
bin/logstash --modules MODULE_NAME [-M
"MODULE_NAME.var.PLUGIN_TYPE.PLUGIN_NAME.VARIABLE_NAME=VALUE"] [-t]
[-w COUNT] [-l LOG]   bin/logstash -e CONFIG_STR [-t] [--log.level
fatal|error|warn|info|debug|trace] [-w COUNT] [-l LOG]   bin/logstash
-i SHELL [--log.level fatal|error|warn|info|debug|trace]   bin/logstash -V [--log.level fatal|error|warn|info|debug|trace]  
bin/logstash --help
[2020-08-14T15:07:51,696][ERROR][org.logstash.Logstash    ]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logstash stopped processing because
of an error: (SystemExit) exit
```

**Edit:**

I tried to use `Filebeat` only. Here I set:

```
processors:
  - add_host_metadata: ~
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
  - add_docker_metadata: ~
  - add_kubernetes_metadata: ~
  - dissect: 
      tokenizer: '"%{event_time} %{loglevel} %{json_message}"' 
      field: "message" 
      target_prefix: "dissect"
  - decode_json_fields: 
      fields: ["json_message"]
```

but that gave me:

> dissect_parsing_error

The tip with removing the "" at `tokenizer` helped. Then I got:

[image: index issue]

I simply refreshed the index and the message was gone. Nice.

But The question is now, how to filter for something in the new field?

[image: kibana filter]

Comment: you should config logstash.yml and make pipeline. you can add pipeline path to pipeline.conf. I suggest you search for sample logstash pipeline config.

Comment: Maybe you have an idea how to do that without logstash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message says, your pipeline config is empty. It seems you did not configured any pipeline yet. Logstash can do the trick ([JSON filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html)), but Filebeat is sufficient here. If you don't want to introduce another Service, this is the better option.

It has the `decode_json_fields` option to transform specific fields containing JSON in your event to a . Here is the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/decode-json-fields.html).

For the future case, where your whole event is a JSON, there is the possibility of parsing in filebeat configuring the `json.message_key` and related `json.*` option.

EDIT - Added filebeat snippet as an [processors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filtering-and-enhancing-data.html) example of [dissecting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/dissect.html) the log line into three fields (event_time, loglevel, json_message). Afterwards the recently extracted field json_message, whose value is a JSON object encoded as a string, will be [decoded](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/decode-json-fields.html) into an JSON structure:

```
 ... 

filebeat.inputs: 
  - type: log 
    paths: 
      - path to your logfile
  
processors: 
  - dissect: 
      tokenizer: '%{event_time} %{loglevel} %{json_message}' 
      field: "message" 
      target_prefix: "dissect"

  - decode_json_fields: 
      fields: ["dissect.json_message"]
      target: ""

  - drop_fields:
      fields: ["dissect.json_message"]


 ...
```

If you want to practice the filebeat processors, try to set the correct event timestamp, taken from the encoded json and written into @timestamp using the [timestamp processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/processor-timestamp.html).

Comment: JSON filter sounds perfect. But I'm not sure which file I need to access and write those filter lines to. Also what happens now with Filebeat? Do I need that tool anymore? Also what about the config, which connection needs to be in there?

Comment: What your scenario looks like? How many machines and how the planned dataflow looks like? If you have serveral machines deploy filebeat on them and try to solve the parsing/mapping already there (filebeat.yml). It sounds to me, this will be the shorter way for you. But if you can't, setup a single logstash and forward the beats events to logstash instead to the cluster directly. Logstash has a logstash.yml and a pipelines.yml. If you need multiple pipelines use the pipelines.yml, for a single edit the logstash.yml. Set there the  location(s) of the logstash pipeline(s) as described here: https

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/dir-layout.html https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/multiple-pipelines.html https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuration.html.  And herr are some examples: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuration.html

Comment: My task is simple. I have a folder with some logs files. And those have this kind of message from the above example. On that machine I now want to be able to search for the message contents.

Comment: OK, try to ommit logstash in favor of beats. Samller and easy to set up. Follow this guide here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/7.8/filebeat-getting-started.html

Comment: Alright, but where the part in Filebeat where I transform the JSON? Maybe you can give me a last hint on that. Will try tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: I added the relevant snippet of filebeat.yml in my answer. I'm glad to help you. Cheers!

Comment: Does not work. `"flags": [ "dissect_parsing_error" ]`. I rechecked the `tokenizer`, but it seems correct. I added the image about how my processors look like. I can't see the issue.

Comment: Please try to remove the double quotes from tokenizer: '%{event_time} %{loglevel} %{json_message}'

Comment: Last question is how can I search now in the new field. It's more a basic usage question I think. Or maybe its not possible to search that JSON? Do I need something else?

Comment: Hey Curtis, is it working? If so, feel free to mark this questuon as solved for future users. If you want to search, do you mean usig kibana or the query dsl?  Grüße!

Comment: I'm also from germany. We can as well continue in Chat if you want. And yes I still have trouble with the query. How to make the query working in Kibana?

Comment: i've opened a room here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220018/room-for-ibexit-and-kwoxer